# jest timeout on express server using supertest

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to test an express app's endpoints using `jest` and `supertest`. Here are my files:

```js
// backend/tests/integration.test.ts
const server = require('../server');
const supertest = require('supertest');
const appTest = supertest(server);

describe('Integration tests', () => {
  it('GET /api/ping', async () => {
    const expected = { status: 200, body: { success: true } }
    const res = await appTest.get('/api/ping');
    expect(res.status).toEqual(expected.status);
    expect(res.body).toEqual(expected.body);
  });
});
```

```js
// backend/server.ts
import app from './src/app';

const PORT = 3000;

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

export default server;
```

```js
// backend/src/app.ts
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/ping', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    'success': true
  });
});

export default app;
```

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: app.address is not a function
```

And the stack trace says that the error is on the line:

```
       8 |   it('GET /api/ping', async () => {
       9 |     const expected = { status: 200, body: { success: true } }
    > 10 |     const res = await appTest.get('/api/ping');
         |                               ^
      11 |     expect(res.status).toEqual(expected.status);
      12 |     expect(res.body).toEqual(expected.body);
      13 |   });
```

My config looks like:

```json
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest"
}
```

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/dist/"],
  transform: {
    '^.+\/*.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest'
  }
};
```

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
};
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "lib": ["es2015"],
  "exclude": [
    "../node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

I don't know why this is happening. Have tried googling & reading about the timeout error on stack overflow but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at **backend/tests/integration.test.ts** just use the server without `http.createServer`

**changes should be made :**

1. instead `const appTest = supertest(http.createServer(server));`
   use `const appTest = supertest(server);`
2. remove done from signature you don't need it if you using async-await , change test signature to `it('GET /api/ping', async () => {...}`
3. remove the done call at the end of the spec
4. add to jest.config  `allowJs: true`,
5. compare versions of dependicies

package.json

```
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^27.2.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes the tests run, but I get `app.address is not a function` when doing `await appTest.get('/api/ping')`

Comment: please update code and output

Comment: Updated the code and output

Comment: update my answer , looks like typescript translation issue try changing to js only for sanity the import and module.exports = server

Comment: That fixed it! ty!!! :)